# Regex to till the first occurrence of the bracket close

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have a string named `cars` which is as follows:

```
cars
[1] "Only one car(52;model-14557) had a good engine(workable condition), others engine were damaged beyond repair"   
[2] "Other car(21, model-155) looked in good condition but car ( 36, model-8878) looked to be in terrible condition."
```

I need to extract the following parts from the string:

```
car(52;model-14557)
car(21, model-155)
car ( 36, model-8878)
```

I tried using the following piece of could to extract it:

```
stringr::str_extract_all(cars, "(.car\\s{0,5}\\(([^]]+)\\))")
```

This gave me the following output:

```
[[1]]
[1] " car(52;model-14557) had a good engine(workable condition)"

[[2]]
[1] " car(21, model-155) looked in good condition but car ( 36, model-8878)"
```

Is there a way in which I could extract the word cars with the associated number and model number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Your regex does not work](https://regex101.com/r/AU17Kz/1) because you are using `[^]]+`, one or more symbols other than `]` that matches `(` and `)`, and thus matches from the first `(` up to the last `)` with no `]` in between.

Use

```
> cars <- c("Only one car(52;model-14557) had a good engine(workable condition), others engine were damaged beyond repair","Other car(21, model-155) looked in good condition but car ( 36, model-8878) looked to be in terrible condition.")
> library(stringr)
> str_extract_all(cars, "\\bcar\\s*\\([^()]+\\)")
[[1]]
[1] "car(52;model-14557)"

[[2]]
[1] "car(21, model-155)"    "car ( 36, model-8878)"
```

The regex is `\bcar\s*\([^()]+\)`, see the [online regex demo here](https://regex101.com/r/OPTJlG/1).

It matches:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `car` - the literal char sequence
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\(` - a literal `(`
- `[^()]+`  - 1 or more chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\)` - a literal `)`.

Note the same regex will yield the same results with the following base R code:

```
> regmatches(cars, gregexpr("\\bcar\\s*\\([^()]+\\)", cars))
[[1]]
[1] "car(52;model-14557)"

[[2]]
[1] "car(21, model-155)"    "car ( 36, model-8878)"
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thank you